# When stopping a service, what's the difference between “Services.msc” and “Task Manager”?

Tags: windows, service, task-manager

When I tried to stop a service with "Task Manager > Services" on Windows 7, it failed saying "Access Denied". But when I tried with "Services.msc", it succeeded. I used the name user.

Why could "Services.msc" succeed when "Task Manager" fails? What's the difference between them?

Do they have different permissions or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely member of the `Administrators` group and your UAC settings are set to `default`.

In this case your user gets elevated and `Services`ist started in the **real administrator context** of your user. Due to the mentioned settings you are not prompted to allow that.

You may set the UAC to the highest level and will be prompted then to allow this operations though.

In contrast, Task Manager always starts in the context of the current user without an upgrade.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Services.msc requires admin rights to modify(run, start, stop, etc.) any of the objects in its list, while task manager does not necessarily require admin rights to modify every one of the processes in its list. You can [run task manager with admin rights](https://superuser.com/questions/1028663/does-task-manager-run-as-administrator-by-default-on-windows-10) to end certain processes that require system level privileges.

Comment: I should change my wording, then.